# Find $x$ as function of $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find $y$ as function of $x$ of:
$$y=\frac{x-1}{x+1}$$

I have tried $$y=\frac{x-1}{x+1}\iff (x+1)y=x-1\iff(x+1)y+1=x$$

Which is of course wrong

Comment: $y$ is already a function of $x$. Did you $x$ as a function of $y$?

Comment: "Which is of course wrong" I see nothing wrong.

Comment: The title and body of your question contradict themselves - I presume you mean what you asked in the title and not in the body

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there:

$$(x+1)y+1=x$$
$$xy + y + 1 = x$$
$$(xy -x) + (y + 1) = 0$$
$$(y-1)x+(y+1)=0$$
$$(y-1)x= -(y+1)$$
$$x=-\frac{y+1}{y-1}$$

**EDIT per comment**

Notice that from $y=\frac{x-1}{x+1}$, it is already guaranteed that $y \ne 1$, and thus we do not need to explicitly specify that.

Comment: @lioness99a Hey, $y\ne 1$ is guaranteed by the fact that $y=\frac{x-1}{x+1}\ne 1$, and thus no need to specify.

Comment: @miracle173 actually good point, will add an inter-step then. (updated with several additional steps)

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying by $1+x$ gives:
\begin{align}yx+y&=x-1\\
yx-x&=-y-1\\
x(y-1)&=-1-y\end{align}

Therefore
$$x=\frac{-1-y}{y-1}$$ if $y\ne 1$

Comment: Actually $y \ne 1$ is guaranteed by the fact that $y=\frac{x−1}{x+1}\ne1$